# Fire speech synthesis events for individual words

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I've been tinkering around with the [**`SpeechSynthesisUtterance`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance) API in JavaScript and have been trying to segment each **spoken word** by the interpreter into a differently fired anonymous function.

Say I have the following sentence spoken through the API:

```
var message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('one two three');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);
```

It will output, *one two three*, although that speed is fine, I am after the ability to attach a function which will fire for the beginning of each of the words, so:

```
* function is called with parameter "one" // starts speaking "one"
* function is called with parameter "two" // starts speaking "two"
* function is called with parameter "three" // starts speaking "three"
```

I have tried to segment these into three different words, for example being spoken at the same time:

```
var message1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('one');
var message2 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('two');
var message3 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('three');

window.speechSynthesis.speak(message1);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(message2);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(message3);
```

But this slowly outputs **"one...... two...... three"** - although this setup would be ideal cause I could attach the `onstart` or `onend` firing events found in the documentation.

Comment: `for example being spoken at the same time` I think is impossible, due to the browser - eg. even from *different tabs*, calling `speak` will cause the last one fired to wait until the first one finishes, even though the first one is in a completely separate tab. I think it can never speak over itself (well, at least in Chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [`SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onboundary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/onboundary) event:

```
var message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('one two three');
message.onboundary = (e => console.log(e));
window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);
```

The event has a `charIndex` property that tells you where the boundary falls in the utterance. It's up to you to read forward from that point up to the next word boundary to determine the word:

```
console.log(e.target.text.substr(e.charIndex).match(/^.+?\b/)[0]);
```

Comment: I'm currently working on trying to implement this, but having trouble getting `e` to give me the exact word it's working on at the time.

Comment: I've just updated with a way to do that, might be helpful?

Comment: You're actually a legend. Thanks for your help mate. :)